# How do I reset the state of a view inside a tabbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewstate, uitabbarcontroller

This is a fairly straightforward question though my Googling session gave me nothing.

How do I reset the state of a view hierarchy located in a tabbar programmatically?  The behavior I want to replicate is when the user tapps on a tab twice. This causes the view located under that tab to return to it's initial state.

The tab is "owned" by a `UINavigationController` and when the user reaches a certain point in the view hierarchy there is a button which I want to connect this behavior to.

All my attempts have failed except calling on a method in AppDelegate which kills the view and adds it back to the `UITabBarController` again. But this does not feel like the right way to go.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards
//Abeansits

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly but I think you should look at

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated: